# EVI not producing values between 1 and -1 Landsat5/7 TM ETM+

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, landsat-7, evi, landsat-5

I am trying to do EVI in ArcMap 10.3. I have done the atmospheric corrections for all the bands needed but cannot get the values between 1 and -1. I have used the formula EVI = G *(Band4 - Band3)/(Band4 +C1*Band3 - C2*Band1 +L) 
L=1, C1 = 6, C2 = 7.5, and G (gain factor) = 2.5.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Or if the formula comes in a different format that could work?

Even better, do you have the exact formula to input into ArcMap raster calculater with brackets in the right place?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.